# How to get a per page total count?

Tags: counters

How could I in the following document replace the X by the correct per-page-total? (29, 31, 20 in my compilation).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{on this page are X objects}

\usepackage{zref-perpage,expl3}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\zmakeperpage{mycounter}

\begin{document}\pdfsetrandomseed 4
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nnnn {1 }{1}{80}
{\refstepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter.~an~object \\
 \int_if_odd:nT {\fp_eval:n { randint( 9 ) }}{some~randomness\\}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to store the expanded number of objects per page in a `\prop` list and extract the value of that list in the header, where the property name is just the page number (hopefully not reset in between); even if the number of objects has to be evaluated more than once (in the loop), this is will update the key - value only (since property - lists have a unique key - value relationship, the potential older value is overwritten)

I tested this with a loop of 5000 iterations (resulting in 169 pages) and the results are correct. (Takes a few seconds, however)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{zref-perpage,expl3}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\zmakeperpage{mycounter}


\lhead{on this page are \propextract\ objects}



\begin{document}\pdfsetrandomseed 4

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn {No,Nx}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn {Nxx}
\cs_new:Npn \propextract{%
  \prop_item:Nx \g_ufischer_object_counter {\thepage}
}
\prop_new:N \g_ufischer_object_counter 
\int_step_inline:nnnn {1 }{1}{80}
{\refstepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter.~an~object \\
 \int_if_odd:nT {\fp_eval:n { randint( 9 ) }}{some~randomness\\}
 \prop_gput:Nxx \g_ufischer_object_counter {\thezpage} {\themycounter}

}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: It fails when different page numberings systems  are used, you need to use `\thepage` instead of `\number\value{page}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That's a design decision then -- your original setup did not have other page numberings

Comment: But your code is not consistent. You are using \thezpage which is a formatted counter to store the values but the unformatted \number\value{page} to retrieve them. But beside this your answer is fine and  helped me to solve my actual problem!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I was in a hurry. I replaced `\number\value{page}` with `\thepage`